# Burninate [mule-choice]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

[mule-choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mule-choice) is used in only 1 question and can be accidentally used as a misspelling of [multiple-choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-choice) (especially when posting from mobile, with a zealous autocorrect)

---

> Tags not associated with any question are automatically destroyed at 03:00 UTC every day.

This tag has one question

> Tags which are misspelled should have the questions under them retagged to the appropriate tag, which will result in its destruction due to having no uses.

This tag is spelled correctly, but might be used as a misspelling

Comment: Also, from that one question, why is there [tag:mule] and [tag:mule-esb]?

Comment: Great point, @NicolBolas. It seems both those tags mean exactly the same thing and they should be merged. I've [created a related question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/371191/3939277)

Comment: @Machavity "Tags not associated with any question are automatically destroyed at 03:00 UTC every day." **This tag has one question**;

"Tags which are misspelled should have the questions under them retagged to the appropriate tag, which will result in its destruction due to having no uses." **This tag is spelled correctly**, but _might_ be used as a misspelling

Comment: @BenLeggiero You do realize that burnination means you're asking for the tag to be removed, right? So I'm confused why you're arguing to keep it now. If it's a bad tag, just delete it from the question. If it's a good tag, then give it an excerpt

Comment: @Machavity I think this tag isn't worth keeping around. I could delete it personally. But, I don't use Mule ESB, nevermind its `<choice>` feature. I don't feel like I should be the one to make that decision; I just figured I should bring it up to the community so we can collectively make that decision.

Comment: **Not a dupe:** This post is not a general question about in general, the misspelled and similar tags. This post is a suggestion to burninate this specific tag, which makes it a non-dupe. I am happy that you at least didn't downvote it to the hell...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like this was just someone's attempt to create a more specific tag. Given how many [mule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mule) questions there are, there's not a solid case why we needed a niche tag here. [564 questions appear related without a sub-tag](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmule%5D+choice)

I've just removed it from that one question. If anyone has issues with that, they can  re-create it with a solid excerpt. I'm about to question the [mule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mule) vs [mule-esb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mule-esb) though. If it is remade, it might not even be this tag.