# The tags [mule] and [mule-esb] mean the same thing

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

[mule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mule) 6,177 Open Qs 1.4k watchers

> Mule is a lightweight Java-based enterprise service bus (ESB) and integration platform that allows developers to connect applications together quickly and easily, enabling them to exchange data. Mule enables easy integration of existing systems, regardless of the different technologies that the applications use, including JMS, Web Services, JDBC, HTTP, and more.

[mule-esb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mule-esb)208 Open Qs (all but 44 also tagged [mule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mule)) 107 watchers Created 1 year, 7 months ago

> Mule, the runtime engine of Anypoint Platform, is a lightweight Java-based enterprise service bus (ESB) and integration platform that allows developers to connect applications together quickly and easily, enabling them to exchange data.

Both tags: 164 Open Qs.

The two tag wikis are almost indistinguishable.

Only two users feature on both Top Answerers All Time lists.

Based mainly on the Usage guides there seems no justification for this [mule-esb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mule-esb) to have a separate existence from [mule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mule).
Given the small numbers involved it is suggested that:

1. [mule-esb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mule-esb) should be removed from Qs already tagged [mule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mule) (manually).
2. 120 Qs should have [mule-esb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mule-esb) replaced by [mule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mule) (manually).
3. If there is a desire to rename [mule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mule) to [mule-esb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mule-esb) a case for this should be made in a separate post  (for mod attention).
4. If those qualified to do so wish, they should suggest (by voting) [mule-esb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mule-esb) be made a synonym of [mule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mule) but this should be in tandem with 1. and 2. given how long synonym suggestions can take to come into effect.

Comment: Related: [Burninate `mule-choice`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/371190/3939277)

Comment: Yeah [mule-esb] is the less ambiguous tag

Comment: @pnuts What's the difference between merging tags and a synonymizing them?

Comment: @BenLeggiero synonym is reversible, the other is not. Synonyms can be created easily by the community, for merges moderators are required. And you lose the tag wiki info on merges.

Comment: Well, the tag wiki for each is... functionally identical, ignoring some formatting decisions. I don't see the need for two wiki entries. But I don't know enough about the processes to propose one way over another. I just think it's silly that they're two distinct tags.

Comment: @pnuts Sorry I don't have time to research the internals of the Stack Exchange moderation process. I just saw this silliness in the tags and figured I'd point it out to the community. I didn't think that entailed learning everything about how to fix it. I thought it would be like filing an issue in an open-source project, where I would be able to describe the expectation vs observation, and someone with more permissions and knowhow would be able to carry out the specifics. I've removed the [tag:synonym-request] tag from this question